# Can not detect Android NDK toolchain

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk, toolchain

I want to build Qt 5.1.2 for Android with toolchain version 4.4.3(for working armeabi libs)
I downloaded latest Android SDK,NDK and other required tools
I also downloaded [ndk-legacy-toolschains](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) and copied the contents under "path_to_ndk/toolchains"
I tried to configure qt5 with below script

```
./configure -android-arch armeabi -android-toolchain-version 4.3.3 -android-ndk-host linux-x86 -developer-build -xplatform android-g++ -nomake tests -nomake examples -android-ndk /home/onurozcelik/Android/android-ndk-r9/ -android-sdk /home/onurozcelik/Android/android-sdk-linux/ -skip qttools -skip qttranslations -skip qtwebkit -skip qtserialport -skip qtwebkit-examples
```

But it fails with: Can not detect Android NDK toolchain. Please use -android-toolchain-version to specify

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: Qt 5.1.2? Is that from git?

Comment: Yeap Qt 5.1.2 is from git

Answer (score 4):

For me it worked to specify:
-android-toolchain-version 4.8

(In the configure script, it seems to look for "$CFG_DEFAULT_ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-$CFG_DEFAULT_ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION/prebuilt", so the given version is inserted after "arm-linux-androideabi-" and this seems to be the compiler version, not the Android version.)

Comment: Sorry. It is my fault. In configure script I wrote `-android-toolchain-version 4.3.3` instead of `-android-toolchain-version 4.4.3`. I successfully built Qt5 for Android armeabi libs